# EF6: How to make Custom Entity from Multiple Tables

Tags: entity-framework, split, dbcontext

Using the Northwind database, I have generated all of the entities from that table using EF6.

Now I would like to create an additional custom entity, which is not an existing table, but it pulls data from three existing tables. The custom entity is "OrderCustomized".

```
public class OrderCustomized
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContactName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
}

public partial class NorthwindEntities : DbContext
{
    public NorthwindEntities()
        : base("name=NorthwindEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderCustomized>()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.Properties(o => new { o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.CustomerID, o.EmployeeID });
                m.ToTable("Order");
            })
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.Properties(c => new { c.CustomerID, c.CustomerContactName, c.CustomerPhone });
                m.ToTable("Customer");
            })
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.Properties(e => new { e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeLastName, e.EmployeeFirstName });
                m.ToTable("Employee");
            })
            ;

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CustomerDemographic> CustomerDemographics { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order_Detail> Order_Details { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Shipper> Shippers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Territory> Territories { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<OrderCustomized> OrdersCustomized { get; set; }
}
```

I keep getting the error "The entity type OrderCustomized is not part of the model for the current context."

How do I made OrderCustomized part of the model for the current context?

I would really appreciate any sample code, as I cannot find any when searching the internet.

Thanks,
Kellie

Answer (score 0):

Remember to update T4 file (.tt extension). Let me know does it work after that operation.